# Matching multiple occurrences of item

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to identify multiple instances of a pattern. In this example, the second sentence contains 'well' twice. How to extract that sentence?

```
example <- c("All's well", "All's well that ends well")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to return only the second string

```
grep("\\bwell\\b.*\\bwell\\b", example, value = TRUE)
#[1] "All's well that ends well"
```

If we are interested in returning sentences that have more than one occurrence of 'well' then use

```
grep("(\\bwell\\b.*){2,}", example, value = TRUE)
#[1] "All's well that ends well"
```

Comment: Hint: For a better understanding how `Regular Expressions` work, look at the very helpful website *www.regexr.com*.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does the 'b' in the code stand for?

Comment: okay, got it (from: www.regexr.com): 'b' stands for 'boundary' ;)